# Как сделать перенос строки после : Text Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Помогите сделать чтобы в виджите Text после символа : и после нажатия на Enter производился перенос строки с 4-мя пробелами.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, задачка интересная:

1. Ловим событие `'<Return>'`.
2. Смотрим какой был предыдущий символ.
3. Если ":", то вставляем пробелы в следующую строку.
4. Отменяем перевод строки от клавиши "enter".

```
from tkinter import *


def insert_spaces(event):
    end_character = text.get('end-2c', 'end-1c')   # получаем предыдущий символ.
    if end_character == ':':
        text.insert('end', '\n    ')   # добавляем пробелы на следующей строке
        return 'break'   # отменяем перевод строки от клавиши Enter
root = Tk()

text = Text(width=100, height=25)
text.pack()
text.focus_set()
text.bind('<Return>', insert_spaces)
root.mainloop()
```

Не хотел вывешивать готовое решение, но может кому-то пригодиться.

Comment: почему то не работает если после : есть пустые строки, что не очевидно сразу. Может как то получше можно символ доставать

Comment: @user184868 Я думаю,  конечно можно, если добавите свое решение я буду только рад.